# Need to create a Totals report from oracle table data

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table in oracle similar to the the example table image that I need to have output the segregated totals as shown in the second example results image.
I need the sums of each item_type where A & B are just examples for a large number of possible items that can be added.

example table:

[image]

example results:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    store,
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_type = 'A' AND item_status = 'IN'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) a_items_in,
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_type = 'A' AND item_status = 'OUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) a_items_out,
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_type = 'B' AND item_status = 'IN'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) b_items_in,
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_type = 'B' AND item_status = 'OUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) b_items_out
FROM mytable
GROUP BY store
```

Comment: Actually I should have added that the item type wont be just A or B but up to 100 or so Items and more could be added so I need the query to sum the item types without having to contimualy add a case to the query when a new item is added if that is possible. thanks

Comment: @JamesJohnson: a sql query must return a *fixed* set of columns. What you are asking for requires dynamic sql, which seems beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @JamesJohnson . . . GMB answered the question that you asked.  If you have another question, I would suggest that you ask it as a *new* question.